# How to ssh to a server from my pc when I am behind a nat (university nat) with no access to university router

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Ok so I am currently studying in a university and my pc is connect via ethernet to the university network.I connect to internet through fortinet portal through my university's id and password.

There is a Fortiguard Firewall installed on my university network which blocks every gaming / proxy sites and ofc steam as well. The only way to access those is to use a VPN which are also blocked (except one or two with free trials with latency way too high).

So I decided to setup a OpenVPN server on Azure VM (free 100$ credit via github student developer pack) and in order to connect to it I need to ssh into it.

While on my university network I tried to ssh on default port 22  `ssh username@public_ip_of_vm` with no success (**connection timed out error**) but when using a VPN (which I talked about above) I can ssh into azure (which defies the whole purpose of setting up VPN on azure). Then on researching a bit I found that I can check whether a port is blocked or not with this command `time nmap -p 22 portquiz.net` which says port 22 as **filtered**.So I guess I cannot ssh over port 22 in anyway. Then when again I checked for port 443 with above command, it said it as **open** and I thought I might be able to ssh over port 443.

So I edited **sshd_config** file on my vm to listen to port 443 and also set the inbound rules in network policy accordingly. But when I tried again to ssh over port 443 `ssh username@public_ip_of_vm -p 443` I got same **connection timed out** error.

So I don't understand why can't I ssh over port 443 or port 80 to azure vm while on my university network?

Also since I have no access to university's router so port-forwarding is not an option.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120958/discussion-on-question-by-tanesh-gupta-how-to-ssh-to-a-server-from-my-pc-when-i).

Answer (score 1):

> So I don't understand why can't I ssh over port 443 or port 80 to azure vm while on my university network?

If HTTP(S) works, but SSH doesn't, all else being equal, then they have an application level firewall that detects the actual protocol spoken, not just the port number and other lower level details. Or they even have a HTTP proxy that captures all HTTP connections. (Hijacking HTTPS is a bit different, if the machine is your own. They'd need to be able install their own root certificate on your system for that.)

Comment: So I guess the only way is to talk to the IT department? However I don't think they will allow SSH in any case

Comment: @TANESHGUPTA, probably. At least by asking nicely you might be able to figure out _why_ they block what they block, if they don't already say it in plain in some documentation. Though in my experience, it may also depend on who you ask and how. People asking about exceptions about security policy can be annoyingly insisting and prone to jump at any weakness of the arguments they receive, even if the person they're talking to doesn't have the authority to change matters. So falling back on "that's how it is", or "rules are rules" is _easier_.

Comment: @TANESHGUPTA, a simpler solution may be to just get another internet connection, if possible, e.g. a mobile one. Though, that being a university, you might have better chances if the access you need is related to your studies, and you can get someone from the teaching faculty to support you. But, of course, that also depends on the local politics.